# Me manda errores al hacer una consulta

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void insert(int Matricula, String Color,Double Precio,String Marca,String Modelo)
{
   try
   {
        String Query = "INSERT INTO coche(matricula,precio,color,marca,modelo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(Query);
        pstmt.setInt(1, Matricula);
        pstmt.setDouble(2, Precio);
        pstmt.setString(3, Color);
        pstmt.setString(4, Marca);
        pstmt.setString(5, Modelo);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt.close();

   } catch (SQLException e){
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Lo uso así:

```
con.insert(matri, color, precio, marca, modelo);
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué errores? Por favor explica bien tu problema.

Comment: Mi problema es que intento registrar un coche dentro de la base de datos y manda el siguiente error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException el insert lo tengo dentro de una vista.

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido al foro. Yo también soy nuevo y estoy contento de haberme registrado!

Podrías enviar una captura de lo que te imprime la función e.getMessage() ?

Así podríamos saber un poco más sobre el origen del problema.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que sea por tu variable **cn** (connection), no veo que esté declarada en el método y al no ser el método static si tienes esa variable como estática creo que tampoco te lo lee.

Prueba crear la conexión en el método:

```
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection( DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)
PreparedStatement pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(Query); 
.....
pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
pstmt.close(); 
cn.close()
```